# Java Threading Deadlock

Tags: multithreading, deadlock

I am reading Java Concurrency in Practice and got stuck on this program,where author say it won't cause the deadlock. But if I swap the method arguments then it will cause deadlock.

```
Obj1 = hash-code =1
Obj2 = hash-code =2
```

`Thread1. transfer(Obj1, Obj2)`  will get lock on fromAcct and will wait for toAcct lock

`Thread2.transfer(Obj2, Obj1)` will get lock on toAcct and will wait for fromAcct lock

So basically we ended-up in dead-lock.

My question is how come is the dead-lock is avoided  in following code.

```
public class InduceLockOrder {
    private static final Object tieLock = new Object();

    public void transferMoney(final Account fromAcct,
                              final Account toAcct,
                              final DollarAmount amount)
            throws InsufficientFundsException {
        class Helper {
            public void transfer() throws InsufficientFundsException {
                if (fromAcct.getBalance().compareTo(amount) < 0)
                    throw new InsufficientFundsException();
                else {
                    fromAcct.debit(amount);
                    toAcct.credit(amount);
                }
            }
        }
        int fromHash = System.identityHashCode(fromAcct);
        int toHash = System.identityHashCode(toAcct);

        if (fromHash < toHash) {
            synchronized (fromAcct) {
                synchronized (toAcct) {
                    new Helper().transfer();
                }
            }
        } else if (fromHash > toHash) {
            synchronized (toAcct) {
                synchronized (fromAcct) {
                    new Helper().transfer();
                }
            }
        } else {
            synchronized (tieLock) {
                synchronized (fromAcct) {
                    synchronized (toAcct) {
                        new Helper().transfer();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface DollarAmount extends Comparable<DollarAmount> {
    }

    interface Account {
        void debit(DollarAmount d);

        void credit(DollarAmount d);

        DollarAmount getBalance();

        int getAcctNo();
    }

    class InsufficientFundsException extends Exception {
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a particular question about this? It isn't clear from what you've currently posted.

Comment: This is the textbook example how to create deadlock.  Acquire locks in the same order.

Comment: That's correct, this the solution to avoid dead-lock but it doesn't  solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your example states that it is in fact correct.

Case 1: `Thread1.transfer(Obj1, Obj2)`

In this case, `fromHash < toHash` so the first lock is on the `fromAcct` param or `Obj1` and the second is on the `toAcct` param or `Obj2`

Case 2: `Thread1.transfer(Obj2, Obj1)`

In this case, `fromHash > toHash` so the first lock is on the `toAcct` param or `Obj1` and the second is on the `fromAcct` param or `Obj2`

Lock order is same, so no deadlock occurs.